# VBA adding validation to multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am sure there is a better way of writing this?
Basically I only want to allow numeric value for data range.
The workbook has multiple worksheets, therefore I only want the code to work on worksheet names WIP and HP
The code works however i feel like i am repeating myself.

```
sub Validation()

Sheets("AKL WIP").Activate

    Range("J9", Range("J91").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(J9)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Data Type Error"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers Are Allowed"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

Sheets("AKL HP").Activate

    Range("J9", Range("J91").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(J9)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Data Type Error"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers Are Allowed"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `Activate` - work with a Worksheet object instead

Something like

```vb
Sub Validation()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' or ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "AKL WIP", "AKL HP"
                With ws.Range("J9", ws.Range("J91").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(J9)"
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = "Data Type Error"
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers Are Allowed"
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error Object not supported debug highlights;  .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(J9)"

Comment: Sorry, I missed one property of the chain - try it now.

Comment: You my friend are a legend.